# Stay close to nature with daily access to Zurich

Tags: switzerland, zurich

In a multi-destination holiday around Europe, Zurich is in my way, and I wish to stay in Switzerland for 3-4 days. However, accommodation in Zurich is quite expensive, and also I wish to enjoy the unique nature of Switzerland.

Therefore, I am looking for a small town around Zurich, as I can find a quite place within Switzerland nature, while I have daily access to Zurich too.

Is there such a place around Zurich? For example, a mountain resort with public transport to the Zurich city center?

Comment: Mountain resorts are unlikely to be cheaper and aren't really convenient if Zürich is your main destination. There are however many small towns that might fit the bill, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrich_S-Bahn

Comment: How long would you want to commute to Zürich? 30 minutes, an hour, 2 hours?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save money, you should look for alternative accommodation systems such as AirBnB or CouchSurfing.

Most hotels will be expensive, even more in a mountain resort. You can probably find a host in the countryside. Use Google Maps or the [SBB website](http://www.sbb.ch) to check if the place you have chosen is at a convenient distance.

Note: Direct trains are fast, but regional trains can be quite slow if they stop a lot. If your accommodation is well connected, you can stay much further from your destination and be on the spot much faster than a geographically closer point but with little public transportation.